# Close HTML tags as soon as one opens them

Tags: emacs, html-mode, sgml-mode

I'd like the corresponding, closing HTML tag to be automatically inserted whenever I open one.

So if I type

```
<div>
```

I should get

```
<div></div>
```

Without having to call to `sgml-close-tag` myself.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than calling a hook function after every single key-stroke, it makes sense to only call it after a <kbd>></kbd> was typed. This can be achieved by rebinding the <kbd>></kbd> character in the keymap that `sgml-mode` uses.

In addition, `sgml-close-tag` shouldn't get called if the tag is already closed. Therefore, the following code adds a simple regexp check for that:

```lisp
(defun my-sgml-insert-gt ()
  "Inserts a `>' character and calls 
`my-sgml-close-tag-if-necessary', leaving point where it is."
  (interactive)
  (insert ">")
  (save-excursion (my-sgml-close-tag-if-necessary)))

(defun my-sgml-close-tag-if-necessary ()
  "Calls sgml-close-tag if the tag immediately before point is
an opening tag that is not followed by a matching closing tag."
  (when (looking-back "<\\s-*\\([^</> \t\r\n]+\\)[^</>]*>")
    (let ((tag (match-string 1)))
      (unless (and (not (sgml-unclosed-tag-p tag))
           (looking-at (concat "\\s-*<\\s-*/\\s-*" tag "\\s-*>")))
    (sgml-close-tag)))))

(eval-after-load "sgml-mode"
  '(define-key sgml-mode-map ">" 'my-sgml-insert-gt))
```

Comment: Great answer! In what cases would one press `>` on an already-closed tag?

Comment: @vernv For instance if you accidentally deleted the '>' character of an opening tag that already has a correct closing tag following. If you re-insert that '>' you don't want yet another closing tag to be inserted.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for empty elements, e.g. `<img/>`.

Comment: @skybert Fixed, but looking at the regex 5 years later, there are other edge cases that won't work. But it's a starting point.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I've ended up with a simple hook like this. As you can see I haven't figured out the 'if applicable' bit, but it works ok enough:
`
(defun  tkj-nxml-close-if-applicable()
  (interactive)
  ;; TODO check to see if we're inside an open element.
  (nxml-balanced-close-start-tag-block))

(eval-after-load "nxml-mode"
    '(define-key nxml-mode-map ">" 'tkj-nxml-close-if-applicable))
`

Comment: @skybert That's probably the sane way to go, but note that the original question was tagged with `html-mode` and `sgml-mode`, not `nxml-mode`.

Comment: Roger that @Thomas.

Answer (score 5):

If you like `paredit` (and if you're an emacs user, chances are you do), you may be interested in `tagedit`, an emacs package written by Magnar Sveen that provides `paredit`-like features for editing html.

The library is here: https://github.com/magnars/tagedit, and can be installed through Melpa/Marmalade (`package-install tagedit`).

If you enable the experimental features `(tagedit-add-experimental-features)`, then it will automatically close tags for you *and* keep the corresponding closing tag text matching the opening tag text. That's on top of being able to splice, slurp, barf and all the other crazy things that `paredit` lets you do when working with balanced expressions...I think it's great!

Comment: Love paredit, I'm definitely trying tagedit out. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `yasnippet` for this purpose.
To type shortcuts this answer, like `<kbd>C-o</kbd>`, I have the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: kbd
# key: kbd
# --
<kbd>$0</kbd>
```

So I type `kbd`<kbd>C-o</kbd> and it get's expanded to `<kbd></kbd>` with cursor
right in the middle. You can have the same behavior for `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You may eval this on your sgml-buffer or add ii to your sgml-hook:

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
          (lambda () (and (eq (char-before) ?>) (sgml-close-tag))) nil t)
```

Whenever you insert a ">", the function `sgml-close-tag` will be run for you

Comment: Can one limit the action of the hook to html-mode? Otherwise one could do a `define-key` with the scope limited to `sgml-mode-map`.

Comment: @vemv, the hook is made buffer local by the code above.  You may enclose it in `(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda ()` and `))` so you have it activated for your html files and only for them.  The `define-key` alternative is also perfectly valid: `(define-key sgml-mode-map ">" (lambda () (interactive) (self-insert-command 1) (sgml-close-tag)))`

Comment: Great to know `add-hook` is buffer-local!

Comment: But only if fourth argument (optional) is non nil, or the hook variable is set as buffer-local (see `C-h v add-hook`)

Answer (score 0):

Using sgml-mode is a pain for me...
When I hit "C-c C-t" in an html file, the minibuffer opens and I enter the attributes... But it keeps asking for more attributes in a infinity loop... If I hit C-g to get out of the non-sense loop, it deletes everything I had entered before.... How do I get out from the sgml-tag minibuffer loop without it erasing my tags in the file?